# Why can't I override Django-registrations's default login form?

Tags: django, django-registration

In my Django application, I'm overriding the normal registration form with a custom one that I have created:

```
from myApp.forms import extendedRegistrationForm

# using my registration form to override the default
url (
    r'^accounts/register/$', 
    'registration.views.register',
    {
        'form_class': extendedRegistrationForm,
        'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend',
    }
),
```

However, when I try to load the website, I get the following error:

```
Could not import registration.views.register. View does not exist in module registration.views.
```

Can someone advise how to get around this obstacle?

Comment: Are you using an old version of django-registration? The current source doesn't have a view named `registration.views.register` - instead it has a class-based view `RegistrationView`.

Comment: Ah, yes! I'm migrating my code from an older instance to a newer instance. In the new instance, I just installed Django-registration fresh. So my code (shown above) is compatible only with the older version. Can you show me how to adapt the code above to work with RegistrationView?

Comment: Clarified question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725400/how-to-migrate-this-code-for-django-registration-to-the-newer-version-of-the-mod