# How to migrate this code for Django-registration to version 1.0 of the module?

Tags: django, django-registration

I have a Django application running an older version Django-Registration. In that application, I'm overriding the normal registration form with a custom one that I have created like so:

```
from myApp.forms import extendedRegistrationForm

# using my registration form to override the default
url (
    r'^accounts/register/$', 
    'registration.views.register',
    {
        'form_class': extendedRegistrationForm,
        'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend',
    }
),
```

It works fine. However, I am now migrating to the current version of Django-registration which I'm told does not have a view named registration.views.register. Instead it has a class-based view RegistrationView. So I get the following error:

```
Could not import registration.views.register. View does not exist in module registration.views.
```

Can someone show me how to adapt my code above to work with RegistrationView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
from registration.views import RegistrationView

register = RegistrationView.as_view()

url (
    r'^accounts/register/$', 
    register,
    {
        'form_class': extendedRegistrationForm,
        'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend',
    }
),
```

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. Sorry. It didn't really work. 
The error I posted went away. But the over-riding the registration is no working correctly. See my new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738954/how-to-over-ride-default-registration-form-in-django-registration-version-1-0

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20739672/805427) answer should solve your problem.